# How can I create a UIView with a Watermarked UIImageView in behind?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I'm not sure watermark is the correct terms here, but what I want to do is the following.

I want to display a UIViewController (there is also a UITabBar on screen). I'm going for a certain look with this UIViewController. I want the entire ViewController to display an image. Then, I want overlay a color overtop of this image with say 80% alpha (i.e transparency). So you see the image faintly in the background.

Then I want to add some UILabel's, UITextField's, and more UIImageView's.

I have a couple of questions.

1) What size image do I need? This application is portrait only. I notice Apple's HIG states that an iPhone 6+ screen size is 1242 x 2208. Does that mean I should have my designer present me with an image that is 1242x2208 to create this UIViewController I want? What about the UITabBar and status bar that are on screen. Will those shrink and skew the image?

2) If I get the image in "iPhone 6+" size, do I scale it down for the other models? 6, 5, 4s? Or do I just create a UIImageView, constrain it to all sides, and then tell it to respect aspect ratio?

3) Do I need this image in question in 4 sizes, specifically for 4s, 5, 6, and 6+. Or do I just get a big image and let it scale itself? Does it need to even be 1242x2208?

3a) Can it be bigger?

3b) Should I avoid going smaller, so it never scales up (and looks weird)?

3c) Does my image need to be created in a 9:16 ratio, like 1242x2208 is?

Answer (score 1):

1) you may need only one (1242 x 2208) if you set the image view's content mode to `aspect fill`; but if the image is POOR CUTTING by the system,you need 4 different image size(eg. iPhone5 may be 640*(1136-tabHeight-statusbar));

2) you'd better use different size image for different device because you may get `MemoryWarning` on iPhone4s if you use a big image.

Answer (score 0):

Your designer can make an image that includes the color overlay in the full size and if she uses a restricted color pallet the file size will be quite small and not present a problem in memory usage. Unless you need precise positioning of the image in all screen sizes one image will work. Use contentMode aspectFill and the aspect ratio will be preserved. The excess image will run off screen. Put the UIImageView at the bottom of your view hierarchy and use constraints to pin it to the edges (as you said.)

Ask your designer to create the image in the png8 file format. This will be good enough for a low contrast image and still have all the resolution intact for large screen sizes. Aspect fill will scale the image to fit without distortion.